# SwiftUI: How to set the title for the toolbar on macOS 11?

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, macos-big-sur

I have a SwiftUI app that has two columns and a toolbar. I'm trying to emulate the latest macOS applications and use the toolbar in the same way that Mail does, i.e. select a sidebar item and show that as the title of the window.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]
var secondItems = ["Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3", "Second 4"]

struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @State var select: String? = "Item 1"
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            NavigationView
            {
                List
                {
                    ForEach((0..<listItems.count), id: \.self)
                    {index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: listItems[index], selection: $select)
                        {
                            Text(listItems[index])
                                .padding(.vertical, 2.0)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.frame(width:160)
            }
            
            .toolbar
            {
                Text("this is not the title")
                Button(action: {})
                {
                    Label("Upload", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View 
{
    var body: some View 
    {
        NavigationView 
        {
            List
            {
                ForEach((0..<secondItems.count), id: \.self)
                {index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(secondItems[index]))
                    {
                        Text(secondItems[index])
                            .frame(height: 20)
                    }
                }
            }.frame(width:150)
        }
        
    }
}
```

So I get a toolbar like this:

[image]

but how do I set the title of the window in the toolbar when I select an item in the first list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
import SwiftUI

var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]
var secondItems = ["Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3", "Second 4"]
struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @State var select: String? = "Item 1"
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            NavigationView
            {
                List
                {
                    ForEach((0..<listItems.count), id: \.self)
                    {index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: listItems[index], selection: $select)
                        {
                            Text(listItems[index])
                                .frame(height: 20)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
                                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            }
            
            .toolbar
            {
                Text("this is not the title")
                Button(action: {})
                {
                    Label("Upload", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(select!)
            .navigationSubtitle("\(listItems.count) records")
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List
            {
                ForEach((0..<secondItems.count), id: \.self)
                {index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(secondItems[index]))
                    {
                        Text(secondItems[index])
                            .frame(height: 20)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what you did to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to change the text that is currently set to "toolbar", you want to set the navigation title. This is done via [`.navigationTitle(String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationtitle(_:)-5di1u) and [`.navigationSubtitle(String)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationsubtitle(_:)-2h20t).

Answer (score 0):

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    ToolView()
    Divider()
    PanelView()
}
.frame(width: 290)
.toolbar(id: "id") {
    ToolbarItem(id: "sidbar", placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Label {
                Text("Stack")
            } icon: {
                Image("stack")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .offset(y: 10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use id to create `ToolbarItem` and you can show the title with right click on the toolbar.
Use `Button` to show the content, and the label and image will fit the toolbar.

NOTE: if you have multiple toolbars, make sure to provide each one with an `id`, or you still won't be able to show the title.
It is best to use `SF Symbols`, but if you use a custom font, make sure to resize it, and offset it.